# Relationship between two vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf b$

Tags: vector-spaces

I am given two vectors, $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$. Knowing that $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are non-zero vectors, and $(\mathbf{a \cdot b)b} = \mathbf{a}$, what is the relation between the directions of $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$? Also, what is $|\mathbf b |$?

Comment: Note for the second part take the dot product with $\mathbf b$ to obtain $(\mathbf{a \cdot b)(b\cdot b)} = (\mathbf{a\cdot b})$ from which you can cancel the non-zero scalar $(\mathbf{a \cdot b)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there exists a scalar $\lambda$ (namely $\lambda =\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b} $) such that $\mathbf{b} = \lambda \mathbf{a}$, the directions of the two vertices are the same (they are collinear). This implies that $|\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}| = |\mathbf{a}||\mathbf{b}|$.

So,
$$|\mathbf{a}| = |(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}) \mathbf{b}| = |\mathbf{a}||\mathbf{b}||\mathbf{b}|$$
which implies that $|\mathbf{b}|=1$

Answer (score 2):

For the first part, recall that $\mathbf{a \cdot b}$  is a scalar. As such, the statement that $(\mathbf{a \cdot b})\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{a}$ is equivalent to saying that $\mathbf{a}$ is a scalar multiple of $\mathbf{b}$. What does this tell you about their directions?

Comment: Does it mean that $\mathbb a$ and $\mathbb b$ are parallel / colinear?

Comment: Yes, they are decidedly collinear.